# Network Printer automatically Cancels jobs

Tags: printer, network-printer

I have a Network Printer (Konica Minolta Bizhub C3350) connected to the network. I'm on Windows 10. I've set the printer using an IP address with same mask and gateway as my computer (mine is at 192.168.25.166 and printer is 192.168.25.108). Windows found the printer easily using the standard TCP/IP port, and I've updated it with the latest drivers.

When I print though (even a test page), it says it sends to the printer, I see it arriving in the queue, then removed from the queue and nothing has been print.

When I log to 192.168.25.108 on a browser I can access the admin pages of the printer. In the Job history, it says the print I tried has a status "Canceled". Details are not providing any more info and I can't find any other logs. From the admin pages, I also tried "Direct Print" and it's working and printing a test document.

I'm not sure what's going on since it seems the printer is working and connected properly.

What do I have to do?

Comment: First thing to check is that you have the **correct** driver installed. Then, check things like paper sizes and the print language are set correctly

Comment: we had a similar problem when printer says `Printing`, but nothing is printing and it turns out it is a dirty sensor in the machine

Answer (score 0):

Try a factory reset on the printer. Type the printer's IP address into your browser, and log in as administrator. Click the System tab, Maintenance and Clear Settings. You can select to clear System Settings, Network Settings or All Settings. Try Network Settings first, if that does not fix it, try All.

Before you do this, make note of the various printer settings, starting with IP settings. If you use it as a scanner, you may have email and folder addresses stored. All of these will need to be re-entered. Start by printing Congifuration pages to help you set it back p.

For more info on resetting the printer, see the [User Manual](https://www.manualslib.com/manual/1189986/Konica-Minolta-Bizhub-C3350.html).

Answer (score 0):

tl;dr:  Install appropriate drivers.

I have a different printer (Dell C1760nw) that had similar behavior... the print would go to the print queue, would show that it printed, but nothing happened.  When watching the printer closely, it would briefly flash "Cancelling job..." then nothing.  And using a web browser to look at the printer, the jobs would show cancelled with no other details.

I my case, the printer was added by autodiscovery (Bonjour) on my macOS system.  It could correctly read the toner levels, and correctly identified itself, but just would not print, even a simple text document that said "test".  I tried manually adding other network printer using LDP, PostScript, and Jet Direct -- all failed the same way.

Finally, I ended up downloading drivers from the OEM.  Dell uses "whitelabeled" printers; I found that the Xerox CP215w is equivalent, and was able to find drivers for my OS from Xerox (now Fuji Film), despite Dell not having them.  After installing their drivers, I was able to add the printer again, select the new drivers, and everything printed fine after that.